# Displaying TIFF tiles on Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Is there a way to display TIFF tiles on Mapbox maps as opposed to PNG tiles. It is possible in Leaflet by creating your own custom tile plugin. But I couldn't find any way to do it on Mapbox except to upload the GeoTIFF file to their Mapbox studio and serve the rendered tiles from there.